# contextMenu dosent work and crash when played

Tags: android

My code crashes in the line  `registerForContextMenu(lv);`

Can you see the problem? i am stuck for hours.

i am trying to connect a listview
i know its something small but i cant find it
please need some help
the code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_boss);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        datasource = new TableInfoDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();
        userPreferences = null;
        userPreferences = datasource.getAllPublications();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        registerForContextMenu(lv); // for context menu!
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(Boss.this, R.layout.simple_list_item_2, userPreferences);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        datasource.close();
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
//                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                Intent intent_employee = new Intent(Boss.this, BossAddJob.class);
                startActivity(intent_employee);
            }
        });


    }

    class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TableInfo> {

        Context context;
        int layoutResourceId;
        ArrayList<TableInfo> data = null;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;


        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<TableInfo> data) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
            this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

 @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.ViewInContextMenu:

                return true;

            case R.id.DeleteInContextMenu:

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Comment: Please also post your logcat errors after the app crashes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: didnt understand can you explain?

Comment: @EvaZana I presume that your ListView is a field, correct? If so, initialize it like this instead: lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

Comment: its already initialize :lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

Comment: @EvaZana Try getting rid of the "android" part, and leave it as "R.id.list". Does it compile? Because, based on the logcat error, your ListView is still null.

Comment: i need to use android list it dosent work without or to configure a list in this activity

Comment: found the problem was configure of list in xml tnx for the help @DaveNOTDavid

Comment: @EvaZana No problem. Check out my answer as I explain it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your ListView initialization:

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

... since you only use the "android" keyword for standard android features that come shipped with the SDK. That said you need to use only "R.id.list" instead which implies that you're referring to a resource file (layout XML file in this case) within your res directory assuming that you have the ListView configured properly in your layout, R.layout.activity_boss.